# Java unreachable code

Tags: java

i create a thread (server) who read string from the input (System.in) and make an output to the client and when i try to close streams 
i get this error : unreachable code when i call this function closeStream() here is the code please help:

```
import java.io.*;
public class ThreadWrite extends Thread{
        private PrintWriter output;
        private BufferedReader inputServer;
        private final boolean test=true;
        public ThreadWrite(PrintWriter out) {
            output = out;
            inputServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        }

        public void run(){
            String send;
            while(test){
                System.out.print("Server:");
                try {
                    send = inputServer.readLine();
                    output.println(send);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            closeStream();
        }

        public void closeStream() throws Exception{
            inputServer.close();
            output.close();
        }


}
```

need your help

Comment: Because you created infinite loop. Variable test is assigned to true and its nowhere changed to false (because you declared it as final cannot be changed btw) in your code. So line after while loop will be never executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`while(test)` always returns true, so the statement following the while loop (`closeStream();`) is not reachable.

Answer (score 1):

You never change `boolean test` to `false` **and you can't (since its final)**  therefore you never move out from `while` loop.

Java

Answer (score 1):

You declared `test` as `final`, so its value can not be changed and will remain `true`.

So inside the `while` condition just the `true` remains and there is no way, that while can ever end (other than Exceptions etc.). Thus the line *after*  the `while` can not be reached.

Answer (score 0):

Test is a final variable which is true. You never leave the

`while(test)`

loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned `closeStream()` outside the `while loop` and condition of is always true and there is no statement in your while loop that breaks it and reaches `closeStream()` method.